# How to move WordPress form HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have following code in my .htaccess file of a wp site

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I have done all the thing need for a WordPress site to operate in HTTPS now my site is opening in both the format i.e in HTTP and HTTPS, but if the user type example.com it goes to http not in https so to solve this I add few more code to solve this issue

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yoursite.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.yoursite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yoursite.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

but after adding this my site in not opening it says "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"

How to solve this issue, I want the user to go directly to https

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not checking if https is being used, so it just constantly tells the browser to go to `https://www.yoursite.com/$1`.

You can use `%{HTTPS}` to check whether the request uses https.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yoursite.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Sorry for so late accepting the answer, I was a noob at that time and did't new how to use SO.

Comment: @RaunakGupta No problem. Better late than never. :)