# Proper code in .htacess file to redirect WordPress HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ssl, redirect

I found a few redirect directives for my Apache Server on different websites. All of them are working fine - but which one is the best? Can anyone explain me which of the following code lines is the best one in terms of performance and logic? The first 3 are very similar. For example:

V2 uses

```
[L,R=301]
```

and V3

```
[R=301,L]
```

All the codes I found (maybe you have a better one)

```
    # V1
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
    
    # V2
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    
    # V3
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
    
    # V4
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yoursite.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move WordPress form HTTP to HTTPS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30893226/how-to-move-wordpress-form-http-to-https)

Comment: @RaunakGupta - I checked the question you mentnioned in your comment - where are the similarities? Please explane?